# How to read text file of data and store it as a multi-dimensional array with Lua

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua

I have a test file with some data on each line (chklist.txt). I am trying to write a function to get that data and store it in a multi-dimensional array.

example of chklist.txt

```
   text1,text1a,text1b,text1c,text1d,text1e,text1f
   text2,text2a,text2b,text2c,text2d,text2e,text2f
```

The text in chklist.txt is in quotes - I have tried single and double quotes.
I want to read this as ChkItem[1][1], ChkItem[1][2]...

So far, I have tried this and several variations of it:

```
function GetCheckList()
  FileNameLIST = SCRIPT_DIRECTORY .. "chklist.txt"
  local f2 = io.open(FileNameLIST)
  for each in f2:lines() do
  indx = indx + 1
    for indx2=1,7 do
      ChkItem[indx] = {}
    end
    ChkItem[indx] = each
  end
  f2:close()
end
```

I have also tried ChkItem[indx] = {each}
and table.insert(ChkItem, each)

table.insert(ChkItem, {each}) gives the complete row in ChkItem[1][1] instead of just text1
with table.insert(ChkItem, each) I get the same complete row with ChkItem[1]

Thank you for any help or insight with this.  I have done this by setting a variable (array) for each line, but I prefer to read the data from a text file.

Comment: read file with `f:read('*a')` and split text with `bigtext:gmatch('([^\r\n]+)')` , after that inside second `for` cycle you can  split the words with `line:gmatch('([^,]+)') `

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike V.  But I'm not sure I follow.  I'm still learning Lua searching Google and following examples.  But I cannot find a solution to this.

Comment: I can add my own answer, but a similar one has already been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to break the lines of text from the file into pieces to create a two-dimensional array.

First, you can loop through lines in a file with a handy method called `lines`. Assume you have a file object called `file`. Looping through it line-by-line is as simple as this:

```
for line in file:lines() do
    -- Do something.
end
```

Using this `lines` method, I wrote a function called `create_array_from_file` that I hope has the functionality you described in your question. The function takes a string, `filename`, as an argument; it uses `string.gmatch` to break each line into individual elements, splitting lines on commas, which is how you separated elements in your example text file.

```
-- This pattern means series of 1 or more characters that are not commas.
local MATCH_PATTERN = "[^,]+"

local function create_array_from_file(filename)
    local file = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
    local arr = {}
    for line in file:lines() do
        local row = {}
        for match in string.gmatch(line, MATCH_PATTERN) do
            table.insert(row, match)
        end
        table.insert(arr, row)
    end
    return arr
end
```

You could change `MATCH_PATTERN` to whatever you want, based on how your input text files are written; alternatively, could include a second parameter for `create_array_from_file` to accept a second argument to be used as the pattern provided to `string.gmatch`.

```
local function create_array_from_file(filename, pattern)
    local file = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
    local arr = {}
    for line in file:lines() do
        local row = {}
        -- Here, `MATCH_PATTERN` is replaced by the function's argument `pattern`.
        for match in string.gmatch(line, pattern) do
            table.insert(row, match)
        end
        table.insert(arr, row)
    end
    return arr
end
```

This second version offers you more flexibility when splitting the lines of your input files.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you Personage!  I used the top version, but will also try the second on in a bit.  The results, though, are what I need.  Thanks again!